# "Unable to find specified file" - Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I wrote this function in my powershell profile:

```
function start {
    if ($args[0] == "blender") {
        Invoke-Item 'C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\blender.exe'
    }
}
```

It gives me the **error** below on **line 1**, at **character 1**:

> Unable to find specified file

The file path is correct, since if I copy and paste the code `Invoke-Item ...` in my powershell it opens Blender normally. **What can the problem be?**

Thank you!

Comment: Don’t you mean -eq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens, as your function name collides with `Start-Process`.:

```
get-alias -Name start

CommandType     Name                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                               -------    ------
Alias           start -> Start-Process
```

Renaming the function is the first step for correction like so,

```
function start-myApps {
    if ($args[0] == "MyApplication") {
        Invoke-Item 'C:\Program Files\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe'
    }
}
```

But that isn't enough, as it gives another an error:

```
Start-MyApps "MyApplication"
= : The term '=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:19
+     if ($args[0] == "MyApplication") {
+                   ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (=:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This one is caused because Powershell's equality [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7) is `-eq`, not `==`.

The working version has different name and operator like so,

```
function start-myApps {
    if ($args[0] -eq "MyApplication") {
        Invoke-Item 'C:\Program Files\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe'
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot for helping, I'm not new to programming but very new to powershell :)

Comment: @EnricoCortinovis Another common pitfall is that function parameters _in defintion_ uses commas, but _calls_ use spaces. If you use commas in a call, the parameters are converted into an array. Third common one is that escape character is backtick - but in regexes it's still the backslash.